# NameError: name 'my_func' is not defined despite import

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python. I have a file `helpers.py` (in the root) with

```
def my_func(integer, tokenizer):
```

and another function in `models/attention.py` (in a `models` subdirectory) that calls that function:

```
from helpers import my_func
....
def another_func(input_seq, tokenizer):
    some_val = my_func(index, tokenizer)
```

PyCharm is quite happy and I can navigate to the `my_func` definition by clicking on it. However, when running or debugging I get an error from the `import` line of `attention.py`.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'my_func'
```

Is it because the helpers module is in the root?

If it's relevant, I'm running Python 3.6 inside a Conda environment on macOS.

**Update**: there's only one `helpers.py` in my code, but others in different libraries:
[image]

**Update 2**: I'm launching from an `evaluate.py` in my root. I added the `print(helpers.__file__)` as suggested and get the expected path:

```
/Users/nic/anaconda2/envs/nmt-keras/bin/python /Users/nic/git/nmt-keras/evaluate.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
/Users/nic/git/nmt-keras/helpers.py
```

I then changed the call to `some_val = helpers.my_func(index, tokenizer)` and it *works* like that! Why?

Comment: is your helpers.py file in the same directory as the script that calls it?

Comment: The message indicates that it can find the `helpers` module, but it can't find `my_func` inside it. Do you have any other files named helper.py in your project directory or on your PATH?

Comment: Thanks MatinaG and Kevin - I've added clarifications above

Comment: Cna you show us your project structure?

Comment: Try `import helpers; print(helpers.__file__)`. This may tell you where Python is looking.